# Concurrency issues with Sequence in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, architecture, database-trigger, database-sequence

I have a sequence in my SQL Server database

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[UserPKSequence] 
AS [int]
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE -2147483648
MAXVALUE 2147483647
NO CACHE 
GO
```

I am using this sequence on a table (lets name the table Users) that has a Primary Key (lets name that UserId) which is not an IDENTITY column. I am using my sequence as the DEFAULT for UserId, as shown below:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [UserId] [INT] NOT NULL 
         CONSTRAINT [DF_User_UserId] DEFAULT (NEXT VALUE FOR [UserPKSequence]),
    [Email] [VARCHAR](254) NULL
    -- other columns defined for the table

    CONSTRAINT [pkUsers] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserId] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The database is used by 2 different applications where both applications can insert data into this table, using the mentioned sequence. Can it cause any concurrency issues? Can one application can get the `UserId` generated by the other application - in case of concurrent requests ? if yes, then how? and what can I do to prevent ? I can not make `UserId IDENTITY`.

Also when a new row is inserted in the table, a trigger is fired which returns the newly generated `UserId` to one of the applications. Can that be problematic?

Comment: You will not get duplicate values from a sequence, unless you specify `CYCLE`, regardless of the number of users.

Comment: Rather than use a trigger to obtain the new value, why not just use the `OUTPUT` clause?

Comment: that causes problems with the first app on which we do not have any control. That application is using Max + 1 approach.